# Wait and notify in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I am handling a thread in my application, I am facing a problem with Thread wait function. I created and show my UI using `runOnUIThread()` , my main thraed was waiting for my UI thread to finish ,after thraed finishes i have do some process in Main thread , here the problem is that Main Process is  always in waiting state even my thread finishes it;s job I am using wait and `notify()` function for this

```
      public String LSVerification() {

        String t = null;

            t="Sample string";
            synchronized(this)

            {
            AndroidHTMLActivity.this.runOnUiThread(ShowDialog) ;//here i call my thread

            try {
               this.wait();//here i waiting for my thread to finish it's job

            //here i do some process after my thread finish it's job
              //the problem is here main process always in wait state


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
          return t;        
        }

        private Runnable ShowDialog = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String t = null;
        synchronized(ShowDialog)

            {
            Recognition recg=new Recognition(Activity.this);

                recg.show();


            this.notify();
            }

            }
        };
```

Comment: i would synchronize both blocks on the same object, else you may have concurrent accesses

Comment: you call this.notitify, meaning you notify ShowDialog, while you wait on this, which is another object. use 1 common object to synchronize, notifiy, and wait.

Comment: even i use same object nothing happen still the main process in waiting state

Comment: are you sure ? can you post the modification you made ?

Comment: i tried in another way it's working for me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use Hanlders to update UI after performing a job in background...

[Link to Handlers](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-1-handlers/) See Code below..

```
private void performOperationInBackgroundThread() {
        Thread Servicethread = new Thread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                PerformThreadOperation();
                                DataLoaded = true;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                ExceptionOccured = true;
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    );
            Servicethread.start();
        }


 static class MyHandler extends Handler{
                MyActiviy parentActivity;
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                    // Update your UI here

                    }
                }

                MyHandler(MyActiviy activity){
                    parentActivity = activity;
                }
            }

MyHandler handler = new MyHandler(this);
```